# Does instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: create a copy of the VC or will the storyboard one be magically not created

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

As a "young iOS padawan" I have the following stupid question to ask -

In Xcode 5 I have created [an iPhone app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyAuth) with [storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H1E9.png) (containing navigation controller, which is managing 3 other view controllers) and the following code in [AppDelegate.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyAuth/MyAuth/AppDelegate.m):

[image: Storyboard screenshot]

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Master"];
    //UIViewController *vc2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
    UIViewController *vc3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"User"];

    User *user = [User load];
    NSArray *controllers = (user ? @[vc1, vc3] : @[vc1]);

    UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [nc setViewControllers:controllers];

    return YES;
}
```

**My question is:** since the `self.window.rootViewController` is used in the above code, this means the Main.storyboard file has already been loaded by the app and the VCs "frozen" in it have been instantiated, right?

Does this mean, that when I call [instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:), then a second **copy** of each VC is created?

And when I set/change a property on a VC later in my app's source code, then the VCs managed by the storyboard are unaffected (but still displayed to the user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the Main.storyboard file has already been loaded by the app

Yes

> when I call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier, then a second copy of each VC is created

Yes, if the view controller is inside the root navigation controller, otherwise no (as the app should have had no reason to load them yet). So, yes for the master view controller, no for the user view controller.

> set/change a property on a VC later

That really depends on the code

The storyboard is a container of, in your words, "frozen" (really archived) view controllers and views. Your code doesn't change the storyboard contents, it just loads different parts of the archive at different times and based on different triggers. Once these elements are created from the storyboard archive you can modify them, but this is a runtime modification based on your code.

Comment: Just to add that loading the storyboard itself in didFinishLaunching doesn't duplicate the load. It's either one or the other - auto load or code in this method. The extra instantiate though are unnecessary/